# mysql: slow queries log: sleep(60)?

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

I am trying to understand what is causing my lamp server to timeout a few times a day since four days, after running fine for 417 days.

Looking at running processes `top` may point to mysql. So I looked in the slow queries log, and only found this.

Can you make sense of it for me?  The line `select sleep(60)`particularly worries me. Especially, since it is not in my website codebase.

```
# Time: 150125 17:16:43
# User@Host: brujobs_live[brujobs_live] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 12.912479  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
use brujobs_live;
SET timestamp=1422202603;
select sleep(60);
# Time: 150125 17:20:17
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 60.000274  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1422202817;
select sleep(60);
```

Comment: [sleep](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep) Why do you have sleep?

Comment: i don't.  it is not in my website codebase. So i'm wondering why it sits in my slow query log file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your event_scheduler is ON.
That would at least explain "sleep(60)".

Read this, it may helps you:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html
- http://mysqlopt.blogspot.co.at/2012/03/mysql-event-scheduler.html